# How do I check if a user may access a given route?

Tags: 8, users, routes

I am trying to render a link from a `Url` object and verify the user actually has access to that URL, like when viewing a node.

For some reason, this always returns `FALSE`, although the node is accessible when `$language` is the set language.

```
$_url = Url::fromRoute('<current>', [], ['language' => $language]);
if ($_url->access()) {
  // The code inside here is never executed.
}
```

How do I verify a user may access the given path, without actually loading the entity behind that path?

---

edit: current state:

```
$currentPath = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
$urlObject = Url::fromUserInput($currentPath);
$routeName = $urlObject->getRouteName();

$linkUrl = Url::fromRoute($routeName, [], ['language' => $dataLangId]);

debug($languageData['languageName']);
debug($linkUrl->toString());

if ($linkUrl->access()) {
  debug('access');
}
else {
  debug('denied');

}
```

results in:

> Some mandatory parameters are missing ("node") to generate a URL for route "entity.node.canonical

Answer (score 5):

I don't know why

```
$_url = Url::fromRoute('', [], ['language' => $language]);
```

Doesn't work with route name `<current>` but it works with other route names.
For example with route with name `some_module.some_route_name` the following 
will work.

```
  $language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
  $_url = Url::fromRoute('some_module.some_route_name', [], ['language' => $language]);
  $userCurrent = \Drupal::currentUser();
  if ($_url->access($userCurrent)) {
    //- Do Stuff
  }
```

In your case for the current route. Try this out.

```
use Drupal\Core\Url;

  $request = \Drupal::request();
  $_url = Url::createFromRequest($request);
  $userCurrent = \Drupal::currentUser();
   if ($_url->access($userCurrent)) {
     //- Do Stuff 
  }
```

Comment: the problem is i dont have the route inside the request. its just an array of links i want to render (or dont render, depending on the access grant)

Comment: also, i try to get the url for the translation

Comment: You can loop through your  array links, and for each element use the following to get the route name .   `$route_name = Url::fromUserInput('your_path')->getRouteName();`

Comment: thanks for your help so far. when i load the route from a node, i obviously get the following error: `Some mandatory parameters are missing ("node") to generate a URL for route "entity.node.canonical` so before loading the route i would need to check whether its a node, a view, etc to pass the needed params. which brings me back to my original question: isnt there a freaking built in function to check if a user has access to a url without having to do all that? :(

Comment: prefix it with / instead of 'node/nid' try '/node/nid'.